# Read multiple txt files into Dict into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I am trying to load multiple txt files into dataframe. I know how to load urls, csv, and excel, but I couldnt find any reference on how to load multiple txt files into dataframe and match with dictionary or viceversa.

the text file are not comma or tab separated just plain text containing plain text song lyrics.

I checked the pandas documents any assistance welcome.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html

**Ideally the dataframe**

the dataframe I hope to achieve would be like this example

```
                 |                                                        lyrics
    -------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bonjovi      |    some text from the text files HiHello! WelcomeThank you Thank you for coming.
    -------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    lukebryan    |    some other text from the text files.Hi.Hello WelcomeThank you Thank you for coming. 
    -------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    johnprine    |    yet some text from the text files. Hi.Hello WelcomeThank you Thank you for coming.
```

**Basic example**
folder structure /lyrics/

```
urls = 

    'lyrics/bonjovi.txt',
    'lyrics/lukebryan.txt',
    'lyrics/johnprine.txt',
    'lyrics/brunomars.txt',
    'lyrics/methodman.txt',
    'lyrics/bobmarley.txt',
    'lyrics/nickcannon.txt',
    'lyrics/weeknd.txt',
    'lyrics/dojacat.txt',
    'lyrics/ladygaga.txt',
    'lyrics/dualipa.txt',
    'lyrics/justinbieber.txt',]
```

**muscian names**

```
bands = ['bonjovi', 'lukebryan', 'johnprine', 'brunomars', 'methodman', 'bobmarley', 'nickcannon', 'weeknd', 'dojacat', 'ladygaga', 'dualipa', 'justinbieber']
```

**Open the text files**
the files are in directory lyrics/ from where I running my Jupyter notebook.

```
for i, c in enumerate(bands):
     with open("lyrics/" + c + ".txt", "wb") as file:
         pickle.dump(lyrics[i], file)
```

## Double check to make sure data has been loaded properly

```
data.keys()
```

**hopefully get result like this**

dict_keys(['bonjovi', 'lukebryan', 'johnprine', 'brunomars', 'methodman', 'bobmarley', 'nickcannon', 'weeknd', 'dojacat', 'ladygaga', 'dualipa', 'justinbieber'])

```
# Combine it!
data_combined = {key: [combine_text(value)] for (key, value) in data.items()}


# We are going to change this to key: artist, value: string format
def combine_text(list_of_text):
    '''Takes a list of text and combines them into one large chunk of text.'''
    combined_text = ' '.join(list_of_text)
    return combined_text
```

## We can either keep it in dictionary format or put it into a pandas dataframe

import pandas as pd

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',150)

data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_combined).transpose()
data_df.columns = ['lyrics']
data_df = data_df.sort_index()
data_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

#get full path of txt file
filePath = []
for file in os.listdir("./lyrics"):
    filePath.append(os.path.join("./lyrics", file))

#pull file name from text file with regex, capturing the text before the .txt   
fileName = re.compile('\\\\(.*)\.txt')

#make empty dict Data with the key as the file name, and the value as the words in the file.
data = {}
for file in filePath:
    #capturing file name
    key = fileName.search(file)
    with open(file, "r") as readFile:
        # note that key[1] is the capture group from our search, and that the text is put into a list.
        data[key[1]] = [readFile.read()]

#make dataframe from dict, and rename columns.
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'bands', 0:'lyrics'})
```

This is how I would do it. Notice I generalized the file manipulation, so I don't have to worry about manually making the list for the keys, and ensure everything matches up.

Comment: Works perfectly, pulling the name from txt is a way better solution too!!. Thanks for the concise comments it help me understand your code.  Again thanks for you time.